# Cython c++ example fails, why?

Tags: python, c++

When I tried to run the example on http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html, I got the following error on the mac terminal:

```
Error compiling Cython file:

 distutils: language = c++
 distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
cdef cppclass Rectangle:


rect.pyx:5:0: Expected an increase in indentation level
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 877, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 997, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: rect.pyx
```

---

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. Could you please tell me why I am getting the error message?

I have Cython 0.23.4 and Python 2.7.10 in my machine. I do not have any problem running the python/c++ codes. I also installed boost and boost-python on my computer.

Briefly, I created the following files:

1-Rectangle.h

2-Rectangle.cpp

3-setup.py

4-rect.pyx

Then, I did "python setup.py build_ext --inplace"

**Rectangle.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
        int x0, y0, x1, y1;
        Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
        ~Rectangle();
        int getLength() const;
        int getHeight() const;
        int getArea() const;
        void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
}
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace shapes;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1) {
    x0 = X0;
    y0 = Y0;
    x1 = X1;
    y1 = Y1;
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {}

int Rectangle::getLength() const {
    return (x1 - x0);
}

int Rectangle::getHeight() const {
    return (y1 - y0);
}

int Rectangle::getArea() const {
    return getLength() * getHeight();
}

void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy) {
    x0 += dx;
    y0 += dy;
    x1 += dx;
    y1 += dy;
}
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
                                        "rect",                                # the extesion name
                                        sources=["rect.pyx", "Rectangle.cpp"], # the Cython source and
                                        # additional C++ source files
                                        language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
                                        )))
```

I tried the following, too:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
           "rect.pyx",                 # our Cython source
           sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
           language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

**rect.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
cdef cppclass Rectangle:
Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
int x0, y0, x1, y1
int getLength() const
int getHeight() const
int getArea() const
void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
cdef Rectangle *thisptr
def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
def __dealloc__(self):
del self.thisptr
def getLength(self):
return self.thisptr.getLength()
def getHeight(self):
return self.thisptr.getHeight()
def getArea(self):
return self.thisptr.getArea()
def move(self, dx, dy):
self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

Comment: You *do* know that python uses indentation instead of curly braces to form blocks? Read again the Error message and then have a look at `rect.pyx`... Somehow you lost all the indentation spaces when copying from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much, swenzel! Now, it works!

**rect.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp
cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getLength()
        int getHeight()  
        int getArea()  
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```